# How to remove defalt value for Jump option in select box on IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'd want to remove default value on IE, As you select a layout with a different number of images in increasing order, drop down goes up with every selection.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, or what you're trying to do

Comment: In IE 11 :- If you select "Saab, Opel ... " then option dropdown goes up,so how am I remove this type of default value on IE,

Comment: You Can see with https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select  dropdown on IE